# Vertica COPY with Pre-Join TABLES

Tags: vertica

I heve two tables Hits and Devices (for example).

```
CREATE TABLE Hits (
  url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  DeviceId INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Devices (
  DeviceId INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  OS VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  Device VARCHAR(30),
);

ALTER TABLE Hits ADD CONSTRAINT fk_devices FOREIGN KEY(DeviceId) REFERENCES Devices(DeviceId);
```

Also, I have a raw data in csv:

```
some url|Android|Device name
another url|Android|Device name
url|iOS|iPhone
url|Android|
```

The raw data are filled in real time and I need to put it to vertica.
Thereis no problem to use COPY to load all data in a single table, but I want to optimize queries and storage. How can I load it?

Comment: In term of performences putting all data in one flat table will provide you the best performence ,as you wil avoid the need for joins (joins in mpp databases like vertica has its own issues) in term of disk space ,Having one flat table will not add high overhad as data is saved in comprision format

Comment: Very strange, because structure in vertica [examples](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.2.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/GettingStartedGuide/Appendix/Tables/Tables.htm%3FTocPath%3DGetting%2520Started%7CAppendix%253A%2520VMart%2520Example%2520Database%2520Schema%252C%2520Tables%252C%2520and%2520Scripts%7C_____1) are not a single table.

Answer (score 1):

Denormalize is best for this situation. For one, the column domains are pretty small. Second, the data is already coming in denormalized.  Save yourself a lot of trouble, and  create a single table.

```
CREATE TABLE Device_Hits (
  url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  OS VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  Device VARCHAR(30),
);
```

Write up a simple COPY statement and load in a representative amount of data. The more you have to start with the better for the Database Designer (DBD) stage.

```
-- You may need LOCAL if you are streaming from a client
-- This works from the node itself as dbadmin
COPY Device_Hits (url, OS, Device)
FROM '/path/to/somefile.csv' DELIMITER '|' DIRECT;
```

Then run admintools and execute the DBD.  If you have any representative queries, put them in a file first so you can tell DBD where to look. DBD will sort and encode the data.

Really, though, this will likely be a whole lot of `RLE` encoding I'd bet.

Definitely don't overcomplicate it with prejoin projections. Those have certain limitations, and quite honestly don't really buy you much in this situation. Vertica is excellent at these types of denormalizations.